# Determining input argument type for jitclass method

Tags: python, class, numpy, numba

I'm working on a jitclass in which one of the methods can accept an input argument of `int`, `float`, or `numpy.ndarray`. I need to be able to determine if the argument is and array or any of the other two types. I've tried using `isinstance` as shown in the `interp` method below:

```
spec = [('x', float64[:]),
        ('y', float64[:])]


@jitclass(spec)
class Lookup:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def interp(self, x0):
        if isinstance(x0, (float, int)):
            result = self._interpolate(x0)
        elif isinstance(x0, np.ndarray):
            result = np.zeros(x0.size)
            for i in range(x0.size):
                result[i] = self._interpolate(x0[i])
        else:
            raise TypeError("`interp` method can only accept types of float, int, or ndarray.")
        return result

    def _interpolate(self, x0):
        x = self.x
        y = self.y
        if x0 < x[0]:
            return y[0]
        elif x0 > x[-1]:
            return y[-1]
        else:
            for i in range(len(x) - 1):
                if x[i] <= x0 <= x[i + 1]:
                    x1, x2 = x[i], x[i + 1]
                    y1, y2 = y[i], y[i + 1]

                    return y1 + (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (x0 - x1)
```

But I get the following error:

```
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'isinstance': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
File "Lookups.py", line 17
[1] During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 'numba.types.misc.ClassInstanceType'>, 'interp') for instance.jitclass.Lookup#2167664ca28<x:array(float64, 1d, A),y:array(float64, 1d, A)>)
[2] During: typing of call at <string> (3)
```

Is there a way to determine whether an input argument is of a certain type when using jitclasses or in nopython mode?

## Edit

I should have mentioned this before but using the `type` built-in also does not seem to work. For example if I replace the `interp` method with:

```
def interp(self, x0):
        if type(x0) == float or type(x0) == int:
            result = self._interpolate(x0)
        elif type(x0) == np.ndarray:
            result = np.zeros(x0.size)
            for i in range(x0.size):
                result[i] = self._interpolate(x0[i])
        else:
            raise TypeError("`interp` method can only accept types of float, int, or ndarray.")
        return result
```

I get the following error:

```
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Invalid usage of == with parameters (class(int64), Function(<class 'float'>))
```

Which I think is referring to the comparison of python `float` and numba's `int64` when I do something like `lookup_object.interp(370)` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're out of luck if you need to determine and compare the type inside a numba `jitclass` or nopython `jit` function because `isinstance` isn't supported at all and `type` supports only on a few numeric types and namedtuples (note that this just returns the type - it's not suitable for comparisons - because `==` isn't implemented for classes inside numba functions).

As of Numba 0.35 the only supported built-ins are (source: [numba documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#built-in-functions)):

> The following built-in functions are supported:
>
> ```
> abs()
> bool
> complex
> divmod()
> enumerate()
> float
> int: only the one-argument form
> iter(): only the one-argument form
> len()
> min()
> max()
> next(): only the one-argument form
> print(): only numbers and strings; no file or sep argument
> range: semantics are similar to those of Python 3 even in Python 2: a range object is returned instead of an array of values.
> round()
> sorted(): the key argument is not supported
> type(): only the one-argument form, and only on some types (e.g. numbers and named tuples)
> zip()
> ```

My suggestion: Use a normal Python class and determine the type there and then forward to `numba.njit`ted functions accordingly:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def _interpolate_one(x, y, x0):
    if x0 < x[0]:
        return y[0]
    elif x0 > x[-1]:
        return y[-1]
    else:
        for i in range(len(x) - 1):
            if x[i] <= x0 <= x[i + 1]:
                x1, x2 = x[i], x[i + 1]
                y1, y2 = y[i], y[i + 1]

                return y1 + (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (x0 - x1)

@nb.njit
def _interpolate_many(x, y, x0):
    result = np.zeros(x0.size, dtype=np.float_)
    for i in range(x0.size):
        result[i] = _interpolate_one(x, y, x0[i])
    return result

class Lookup:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def interp(self, x0):
        if isinstance(x0, (float, int)):
            result = _interpolate_one(self.x, self.y, x0)
        elif isinstance(x0, np.ndarray):
            result = _interpolate_many(self.x, self.y, x0)
        else:
            raise TypeError("`interp` method can only accept types of float, int, or ndarray.")
        return result
```

Comment: In case your `x` and `y` are really big (and sorted) you might want to use some sort of bisection. It shouldn't be too complicated to change one of Pythons [`bisect`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/bisect.py) functions so that it compiles when `nb.njit`ted.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. Hopefully in the future they support some form of overloading for njitted methods/functions. I ended up doing basically as you said but with a static method for "one" and "many" cases.

Answer (score 2):

As of numba 0.52, `np.shape()` is supported. So if you only want to distinguish between `np.ndarray` and scalars, the following works:

```py
@njit
def test(a):
    if len(np.shape(a)) > 0:
        return 'np.ndarray'
    else:
        return 'not an array'
```

```
>>> test(1)
'not an array'
>>> test(np.array([1,2,3]))
'np.ndarray'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but you could try using `objmode`:

```
@njit
def isarray(obj):
    with objmode(isarray="boolean"):
        isarray = isinstance(obj, np.ndarray)
    return isarray
```

and then use `isarray(x0)` instead of `isinstance(x0, np.ndarray)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of substituting the required function implementation depending on the argument type.

Tested on numba 0.57.1

```
import numba as nb
import numba.experimental as nbexp
import numba.extending as nbex
from numba import types as nbt

@nbexp.jitclass([ ('_x', nbt.float32),
                  ('_y', nbt.float32), ])
class Vec2:
    def __init__(self, x : float, y : float):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @property
    def x(self) -> float: return self._x
    @property
    def y(self) -> float: return self._y

    def __mul__(self, other): return Vec2(0,0) # overloaded

    
# Overload implementations
def Vec2__mul__Vec2(self, other):   return Vec2(self._x*other._x, self._y*other._y)
def Vec2__mul__number(self, other): return Vec2(self._x*float(other), self._y*float(other))

# Overloaders
@nbex.overload_method(nbt.misc.ClassInstanceType, "__mul__")
def over_Vec2__mul__(self, other):
    if self is Vec2.class_type.instance_type:
        if other is Vec2.class_type.instance_type: return Vec2__mul__Vec2
        if other in nbt.number_domain: return Vec2__mul__number

# Tests

@nb.njit(nogil=True)
def run_test1():
    return Vec2(1,1) * 2

@nb.njit(nogil=True)
def run_test2():
    return Vec2(1,1) * Vec2(3,3)

print( run_test1().x ) # outputs 2.0
print( run_test2().x ) # outputs 3.0
```

Answer (score -2):

use `type()`?

```
blah = []
if type(blah) is list:
    print "Is a list"

blah = 5
if type(blah) is int:
    print "we have an int"
```

ie:

```
>>> blah = 5
>>> type(blah)
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

Comment: @HughBothwell See the error in the question for why isinstance did not work. This was my first choice.

Comment: I tried using type, but this also did not work. I've edited the question to show this as well.

Comment: After reading some , and googling, try `isinstance(x0, (int, np.uint))`